# Calculate Diagonal Values By Two Dates and Prepare Matrix in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I can calculate the diagonal values according to 2 different dates, but my aim is that create this measure for a matrix with row "customer" and one of the dates.

Here is the sample data,

| StartYear | StartMonth | CalcYear | CalcMonth | Customer | ff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 1 | 100 | **0.00** |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 2 | 100 | 0.00 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 3 | 100 | 0.00 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 4 | 100 | 0.00 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 6 | 100 | 0.00 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 7 | 100 | 41.07 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 8 | 100 | 115.93 |
| 2023 | 1 | 2023 | 9 | 100 | 62.23 |
| 2023 | 3 | 2023 | 3 | 100 | **0.00** |
| 2023 | 3 | 2023 | 4 | 100 | 0.00 |
| 2023 | 3 | 2023 | 6 | 100 | 0.00 |
| 2023 | 3 | 2023 | 7 | 100 | 41.07 |
| 2023 | 3 | 2023 | 8 | 100 | 57.97 |
| 2023 | 5 | 2023 | 5 | 100 | **0.00** |
| 2023 | 5 | 2023 | 11 | 100 | 77.95 |
| 2023 | 6 | 2023 | 6 | 100 | **0.00** |
| 2023 | 6 | 2023 | 7 | 100 | 82.13 |
| 2023 | 6 | 2023 | 12 | 100 | 100.88 |
| 2023 | 6 | 2024 | 1 | 100 | 131.92 |
| 2023 | 7 | 2023 | 7 | 100 | **1,190.93** |
| 2023 | 7 | 2023 | 8 | 100 | 289.83 |
| 2023 | 7 | 2023 | 9 | 100 | 248.93 |
| 2023 | 7 | 2023 | 10 | 100 | 329.81 |
| 2023 | 7 | 2023 | 11 | 100 | 155.91 |
| 2023 | 7 | 2023 | 12 | 100 | 403.53 |
| 2023 | 7 | 2024 | 1 | 100 | 263.85 |
| 2023 | 8 | 2023 | 8 | 100 | **1,681.03** |
| 2023 | 8 | 2023 | 9 | 100 | 622.33 |
| 2023 | 8 | 2023 | 10 | 100 | 329.81 |
| 2023 | 8 | 2023 | 11 | 100 | 311.82 |
| 2023 | 8 | 2023 | 12 | 100 | 201.76 |
| 2023 | 8 | 2024 | 1 | 100 | 263.85 |
| 2023 | 9 | 2023 | 9 | 100 | **1,867.00** |
| 2023 | 9 | 2023 | 10 | 100 | 593.65 |
| 2023 | 9 | 2023 | 11 | 100 | 77.95 |
| 2023 | 9 | 2023 | 12 | 100 | 302.65 |
| 2023 | 9 | 2024 | 1 | 100 | 131.92 |
| 2023 | 10 | 2023 | 10 | 100 | **1,715.00** |
| 2023 | 10 | 2023 | 11 | 100 | 467.73 |
| 2023 | 10 | 2023 | 12 | 100 | 201.76 |
| 2023 | 10 | 2024 | 1 | 100 | 131.92 |
| 2023 | 11 | 2023 | 11 | 100 | **1,715.00** |
| 2023 | 11 | 2023 | 12 | 100 | 201.76 |
| 2023 | 11 | 2024 | 1 | 100 | 395.77 |
| 2023 | 12 | 2023 | 12 | 100 | **1,715.00** |
| 2023 | 12 | 2024 | 1 | 100 | 263.85 |

The measure that calculates the diagonal values:

```
FF = 
 VAR startyear=SELECTEDVALUE(table[StartYear])
 VAR startmonth=SELECTEDVALUE(table[StartMonth])
RETURN
 CALCULATE (
    SUM(table[FixedFee]),
    FILTER(table,startyear=table[CalcYear] && startmonth=table[CalcMonth])
)
```

The matrix with customer is on row, calcyear/month is on column and measure above is on value looks like

[image]

And my aim matrix to reach out,

|  | CalcYear | 2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer | CalcMonth | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 100 |  | 0 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 100 | 100 | 1190 | 1681 | 1867 | 1715 | 1715 | 1715 |

Thank you,

Veli

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
FF = 
  CALCULATE (
    SUM('table'[FixedFee]),
    FILTER(
      'table',
      'table'[StartMonth] = 'table'[CalcMonth] && 
      'table'[StartYear] = 'table'[CalcYear]
    )
  )
```

Comment: this measure works on the table that contains both date info, otherwise it turns blank.

Comment: As per your question "aim matrix".  Which other matrix configuration are you wanting? On my end, with no `CalcMonth` or `CalcYear` in the visual, it still works.

Comment: I've updated the post with blank matrix. When I put the customer on the row, calcyear/month on column and measure above on values, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Perhaps update the question with what your tables are.